# Passing argument from Spring Controller to javascript

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring

I try to pass argument from spring controller to javascript.
I got error Error:

```
[ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.16/ng/areq?p0=mainController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:8080/asreports/resources/js/angular.min.js:6:417
    at Sb (http://localhost:8080/asreports/resources/js/angular.min.js:19:510)
    at La (http://localhost:8080/asreports/resources/js/angular.min.js:20:78)
    at $get (http://localhost:8080/asreports/resources/js/angular.min.js:75:465)
    at compile (http://localhost:8080/asreports/resources/js/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:23333)
    at Xc (http://localhost:8080/asreports/resources/js/angular.min.js:70:279)
    at M (http://localhost:8080/asreports/resources/js/angular.min.js:59:323)
    at g (http://localhost:8080/asreports/resources/js/angular.min.js:51:409)
    at http://localhost:8080/asreports/resources/js/angular.min.js:51:17
```

If i delete "${variable}" from controller everything work fine.

**My javascript**

```js
"use strict"

myapp.controllers = {};

myapp.controllers.main = ['$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state) {

 $scope.casedet = ${variable};

} ];

app.controller('mainController', myapp.controllers.main)
```

**My model**

```html
model.addAttribute("variable", selectedCase);
```

Comment: What is the type of your variable(selectedCase)  ? Is it a string ?

Comment: selectedCase is an object